# How to pass data from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

I want to pass Bitmap from fragment to the MainActivity. I want to save the bitmap i.e in "image = a.getParcelable("BITMAP"); " on ActionBar button click. For that i need this image in my MainActivity. How can i do that?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Inflate the layout for this fragment

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    Bundle a = getArguments();

    image = a.getParcelable("BITMAP");

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);

    qImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.qImage);

    qImage.setImageBitmap(image);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Android docs describe the common way of communicating with activity http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MainActivity

```
Bitmap a;
```

In Fragment

```
MainAcivity main;
main = (MainActivity)getActivity();
main.a = image
```

or call a method on the MainActivity to update Bitmap